# Deleted python3.5 in /usr/local/bin

Tags: command-line, python, uninstall

Unadvisedly, I went to /usr/local/bin and deleted the folder

```
rm -r python3.5
```

The folder /usr/local/bin used to have two folders: python2.7 and python3.5. Now it only has python2.7.

However, when I ran python3 in the terminal, it was still working. Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.5
```

But the folder /usr/local/bin still has only python2.7.

So what did I really do when I deleted python3.5 folder. If that's a problem, how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK packages from official Ubuntu repositories don't install anything into /usr/local - likely you have deleted some third-party and/or manually installed python3.5 components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/usr/local` is not an area touched by official packages.  If you removed the directory from `/usr/local/bin`, you likely deleted a locally-compiled or locally-installed Python copy, which won't affect the system `/usr/bin/python*` binaries.